# How to use production BlobStore in development server (Google App Engine)

Tags: python, image, google-app-engine, blobstore

I'm developing an application on Python Google App Engine and I'm using the BlobStore to store image data.

I've backed up all my database information to my local host to set up a local development environment but I want to use the Blobs Images from my Production server (so I don't have to copy all files to my local computer).

When I call images.get_serving_url() to get the image url it returns a local reference to it that doesn't exist (since all the images are in the prod server).

Is there a way to configure the images class to point to my prod server? If the answer is no, how can I redirect the calls from my dev server that hit /_ah/img/ to my prod server?

```
from google.appengine.api import images
print images.get_serving_url(page, size=100)

>> http://0.0.0.0:8080/_ah/img/AMIfv96IySWiIWF-4FRipavsn9xXnkk-EhmNOU0qWZ4y0ORIXj0Ct85C9eXMBdv3JVooWPIm6-2D3U9ffuTtpJEkWh13ZzmmaNKSiu5QMsnk0exNWj7g1OWbpNxcsjtmv52wz94QFQ6xCNz-atycTqfkdDHbX-LWmMqlsrVEs86S4wsAKSNOZZE=s100
```

I wish the output from this call was my prod server url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're asking isn't possible.

The image blob keys are more or less randomly generated.  ie, when you upload a blob to the production Blobstore, it gets a key generated.

There's no way for the dev appserver to know the key for a given image on the production server.  If you "upload" the same image to the dev_appserver, it'll get a completely different key.

Your options are either to download all the images locally and "upload" them to your local dev server.  If you're using Google Cloud Storage, the gsutil tool might help: https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil

Or find all the blobstore urls on the server and manually map them in your own application.

Comment: I've just checked the blobkey of a particulat file in my production and development server and they are the same:

Prod: AMIfv95f38Dp3bPn5ftLXS2G0sEwf043tDDeHZA6Dp9qHB8Q5I-uJ7GyOzQ-U-a1_14zgR8s4b2Gn6Osq7arwCUhna5HFEcwAGUJXMM4lW8y_ZJQUQ2Imz5wHRLGQk1EVeW7_KDSydk6B8K-Ql_xE3cBYYEyeEVbqw

Development: AMIfv95f38Dp3bPn5ftLXS2G0sEwf043tDDeHZA6Dp9qHB8Q5I-uJ7GyOzQ-U a1_14zgR8s4b2Gn6Osq7arwCUhna5HFEcwAGUJXMM4lW8y_ZJQUQ2Imz5wHRLGQk1EVeW7_KDSydk6B8K-Ql_xE3cBYYEyeEVbqw

I think that happened because we've used the database from the production server to load our local development environment.

Comment: Sorry I neglected to consider that.  You're still kinda screwed, because get_serving_url() still returns vastly different urls.  You'd want to call get_serving_url() on the server side and store that url in the datastore, and use that in your dev server.  I know you're going to balk at that since you'll have to download the data again, but there's a benefit to this: get_serving_url() is slow, and you'll improve the perf off your app if you store that url and use it on production instead of constantly calling get_serving_url()

Comment: How do I discover If my Blobs are hosted in the BlobStore or in Google Cloud Storage?

Comment: Depends which API you used to upload the file.

Comment: According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29905511/2697279) you cannot currently use `gsutil` to upload files to your local dev server.