# Can I use gsutil with my local development server?

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud, gsutil

I'm developing a google app engine application that uses cloud storage. I want to have a base set of files on the cloud storage that are shared by each user of the application. I know I can use gsutil to copy these files to the production server.

But I would like to test my application on my local development server, so I need these files in the dev cloud storage as well. I can't find any way  to copy the files. Is there a way to use gsutil to copy files to the development server's cloud storage simuation?

Answer (score 1):

We don't currently support the full GCS API in the local dev server.

Your best bet is to probably just write to a different bucket when running locally for now.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "just write to a different bucket"? I'm not sure how that is a workaround for my problem.